# ros::time corresponding to message sent

Tags: ros, callback, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to recover the ROS time when a message was sent?  I'm doing some clock synchronization with another package with custom messages that don't include a ros time in the message definition.  With network latency and whatnot, I can't get use ros::Time::now() for synchronization.

EDIT:  The ros time of receipt within a rosbag would also be a help, if there's a way to recover it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293061/ros::time-corresponding-to-message-sent/) by [Nick30075](https://answers.ros.org/users/30974/nick30075/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, afaik the time a message was published is only available if the sender has added that to the message (and even then it's an approximation, as they will probably use `ros::Time::now()`.

The [MessageEvent](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#MessageEvent_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D) class can provide you with some additional information, such as when a message was received (by your node), but not when it was sent unfortunately.

Also see [wiki/ROS/Connection Header](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Connection%20Header) for some more fields that can be accessed that way.

> I'm doing some clock synchronization with another package with custom messages that don't include a ros time in the message definition.

To synchronise data between nodes a `Header` (or similar structure) is required, and I would say, is actually exactly what it was intended for. But you probably already knew that.

> EDIT: The ros time of receipt within a rosbag would also be a help, if there's a way to recover it.

See #q199941.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1